# How do you check if a polynomial system has solutions

Tags: polynomials, nonlinear-system

Given the polynomials

$f(x,y)=4x^{12}+7y^{18}-1=0$ and $g(x,y)=5x^{10}+9y^{14}-1=0$

I have to figure out:

a) if the real solutions set of the above system is empty or not

b) if the set of real solutions is finite or infinite and the maximum number of solutions in the set

I don't really know how to to solve the first one.. But I suspect that it should be not empty so that I can go on with the rest of the questions.

a) ?

b) Since the only polynomial that has infinite solutions is $f(x,y)=0$ and the polynomials of the given system are diferent than that, then the system has finite solutions. Also if $n$ is the number of roots of $f(x,y)$ and $m$ is the number of roots of $g(x,y)$ then the solutions of the system is $s=min\left \{ n,m \right \}$

Any ideas on a) ? Also do you think my solution to b) is correct?

Comment: For a), you need to find out whether the ideal $\langle f,g\rangle$ is zero-dimensional. Not sure how deep you are in algebraic geometry?

Comment: There are no real solutions of your system.

Comment: What do you mean by "Since the only polynomial that has infinite solutions is (,)=0..."?   Are you looking for real solutions or complex solutions?

Comment: I'm lookin for real solution (just edited). Also @Dr.SonnhardGraubner how do you prove that it has no real solutions? Is it like Wuestenflux suggested?

Comment: No, i have computed a Gröbner base of it.

Comment: Even though I'm very well familiar with the Groebner basis, at the request of my tutor we cannot use it to solve the problem

Comment: Here it is $$\left\{6511376158623 y^{126}-6511376158623 y^{112}+2893944959388 y^{98}-557900384508
   y^{84}-3207423582 y^{70}+21732118398 y^{56}-2654079048 y^{42}-140741712 y^{28}+40875867
   y^{14}+110818,562890625 x^2-393576514476768 y^{112}+349845790646016
   y^{98}-136051140806784 y^{84}+22078713274452 y^{70}+331376033340 y^{56}-633520356408
   y^{42}+48310133481 y^{28}+3958607826 y^{14}-399648883\right\}$$

Comment: See also here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4*x%5E12%2B7*y%5E18%3D1,5*x%5E10%2B9*y%5E14%3D1

Comment: The solutions of the single equations are curves (almost rectangles in this case). Thus have an infinity of solutions. The intersection of these curves can only have up to $\deg f\cdot\deg g$ isolated, transversal intersection points (apart from possible common components). These counts are for complex solutions, the number of real solutions can be dramatically lower.

Comment: On your soln b) Consider the polynomial equation $x-y=0$.  It is not zero, however it has infinite solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an elementary way to show there are no real solutions:

$$5x^{10}+9y^{14}=1 \implies x^{10} \leqslant \tfrac15,\: y^{14} \leqslant \tfrac19$$

$$\implies 4x^{12}+7y^{18}\leqslant \frac4{5^{6/5}}+\frac7{9^{9/7}}<1$$

Answer (score 1):

According to Maple, the resultant of $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ is

$$ R(y)= \left( 262609375\,{y}^{90}+544195584\,{y}^{84}-187578125\,{y}^{72}-
362797056\,{y}^{70}+100776960\,{y}^{56}+53593750\,{y}^{54}-14929920\,{
y}^{42}-7656250\,{y}^{36}+1244160\,{y}^{28}+546875\,{y}^{18}-55296\,{y
}^{14}-14601 \right) ^{2}
$$
and $R(y)$ has two real roots: these are approximately $\pm 0.8815209409$ (symmetric, of course, since the equations only depend on $y^2$).
However, for these values of $y$ the common roots of $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ are non-real.  We conclude there are no real solutions.